# Cannot See Stored Procedure on Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

First, I know the syntax of calling a procedure on a linked server and I am familiar with the RPC and RPC Out server options at a basic level. What I am being told is that a procedure I created cannot be seen by navigating the tree of the linked server.

One caveat is I do not have access to the server where this person is working which is linked to the server on which I have the procedure - I hope that is clearly stated. At this time he is getting the "not configured for RPC" error on execution and I have told him to check the linked servers options. So ultimately, do the RPC linked server options control whether the procedure can be seen?

I've been told that other views can be seen. Also, I am confident it is not a permissions issue. The user involved has access to a role which has access to my procedure.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Some code would be helpful here :) For a linked server and sql statement at least. The most probable reason in my opinion is using wrong db schema name is execute statement.

Comment: Try looking at permissions again, you have to make sure the Link user (The link to the server is done by a different user than the calling user) has execute permissions fro that stored procedure (This has happened to me and it took forever to trouble shoot)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the Linked Server, Properties, Server Options there are two RPC settings.
Set them both to true.

What do you mean by do not have access?
You cannot Connect to that server?
That is how I tested this.
Connect to any server, create a Linked Server back to yours, and test.

Comment: Setting the RPC Out value to true allows my colleague to execute the procedure, however, he still cannot see it navigating the tree. In the tree he only sees Views and Tables. I'm just curious why.

Comment: All I see in Linked Server is tables and views.  Clearly you have access to another server.  Create a test database and see for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

This is true: 
In the Linked Server, Properties, Server Options there are two RPC settings.
 Set them both to true.

You also need to verify that the credentials used inside the linked server connection has rights on the linked server.

Grant connect, and access to the database that has the stored procedures that you need access too. You will then grant execute to the procedures you need to run.

If you have connection issues, open SSMS using the credentials you have used to create the linked server on the database server you are trying to link from and verify connectivity and database access. If you can see the objects your after, then the linkedserver connection is the problem. Try creating a new one and see if you have better luck that way.